# Logging uncaught exceptions in threads created by third-party code in web application

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish, uncaught-exception

I suspect a thread created by a third-party jar used by my web application may be throwing an exception, and not catching it. However, I don't see any evidence of this in the log files. How can I force all uncaught exceptions to be dumped to a log file? This is for a web app running inside Glassfish.

Comment: virtually any container i know of catches exceptions (or Throwable) so Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler won't help. The solution is wrapping the invocation in try/catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is not necessary with Glassfish, because Glassfish already does it - but I was looking at the wrong place in the logs.

The exception was printed to the main `server.log` file - not to my application's own log4j log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the uncaught exception handler.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=229

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default uncaught exception handler using `Thread's` `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` static method:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException( final Thread t, final Throwable e ) {
                ...
```